# why json.dumps add \n in the output,how should I remove it while saving it in a file?

Tags: python-3.x

Why does `json.dumps` add `\n` in the output, and how should I remove it while saving it in a file?

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import json
>>> data = {'people':[{'name': 'Scott', 'website': 'stackabuse.com', 'from': 'Nebraska'}]}
>>> json.dumps(data, indent=4)
'{\n    "people": [\n        {\n            "website": "stackabuse.com",\n            "from": "Nebraska",\n            "name": "Scott"\n        }\n    ]\n}'
>>>
```

Comment: If you use `print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))` does it look more like you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using pretty print, if you want to avoid new lines do not use indent flag.

```
import json

data = {'people': [{'name': 'Scott', 'website': 'stackabuse.com', 'from': 'Nebraska'}]}

print(json.dumps(data))

{"people": [{"name": "Scott", "website": "stackabuse.com", "from": "Nebraska"}]}
```

Your version just use nice formatting:

```
import json

data = {'people': [{'name': 'Scott', 'website': 'stackabuse.com', 'from': 'Nebraska'}]}

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

{
    "people": [
        {
            "name": "Scott",
            "website": "stackabuse.com",
            "from": "Nebraska"
        }
    ]
}
```

In addition - new lines have no matter for json. Below two examples works same:

```
import json

data = {'people': [{'name': 'Scott', 'website': 'stackabuse.com', 'from': 'Nebraska'}]}

with open('/tmp/file1', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

with open('/tmp/file2', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)

with open('/tmp/file1') as f:
    print(json.load(f))

with open('/tmp/file2') as f:
    print(json.load(f))

{'people': [{'name': 'Scott', 'website': 'stackabuse.com', 'from': 'Nebraska'}]}
{'people': [{'name': 'Scott', 'website': 'stackabuse.com', 'from': 'Nebraska'}]}
```

Comment: I'm not using pretty print or indent, I'm still getting \ before all my double quotes in my printed dict. Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Because you ask it to, by providing `indent`. Just doing `json.dumps(data)` will not insert any newlines.